# taking a picture in iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c

i cannot seem to get this right. ive looked at several tutorials with no luck. i realize it is a simple task, which is why i am so confused on why it isnt working for me. 
i have a programmatically made button inside an expanding cell and when you press it, it is suppose to access the camera to take a picture. i have this code:

```
- (void)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)button {
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    [picker setDelegate:self];
    //picker.allowsImageEditing = NO;
    [self presentModalExpandingCell:picker animated:YES];

    picker.showsCameraControls = YES;
}
```

the error appears in line 5. and says "no visible @interface for 'ExpandingCell' declares the selector 'presentModalExpandingCell:animated:'" i have "" in the .h file so i have no idea what to do.
any help will be greatly appreciated. thanks in advance.

Comment: Check your presentModalExpandingCell:animated: method

Comment: i followed a tutorial and this is what it go me. in the tutorial it said viewcontroller rather than expandingcell other than that i did everything they did. they didnt declare anything for that method.

Comment: Probably there is an error, instead of [self presentModalExpandingCell:picker animated:YES]; use this
[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: the same error appears.. would you be willing to email or skype and help me figure this out? i do not have much ios experience and would love some help with this app.

Comment: okay! i sent you a request!

Comment: write me on mail gronzzz@gmail.com, my skype is very bad

Answer (score 0):

Have you declared the method "presentModalExpandingCell" in your class?  Because, if not, that is why the compiler is throwing that error.

Comment: i followed a tutorial and this is what it go me. in the tutorial it said viewcontroller rather than expandingcell other than that i did everything they did. they didnt declare anything for that method.